# Set @class on ActionLink based on current action

Tags: asp.net, razor

I have a simple menu with actionlinks. They're all connected to the same controller. I want them to have one basic HTML-class, unless they're the active action, then I want to set another class. 
The links just switch between the data to be shown.

I've tried the following:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Oversikt", "Overview", "Statistics", null, new {@class= @(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"] as String == "Overview"  ? "activeStatMenuItem" : "statMenuItem") })
```

[image: First compilation error]

I thought it maybe missed the `@` in front of ViewContext, but that didn't help, so I tried making everything a string. That makes Visual Studio complain about the strings (and it also gives a compilation error).

[image: Complaining about the Strings]

If I also add it on the classes, like;

```
@Html.ActionLink("Oversikt", "Overview", "Statistics", null, new {@class= "@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values['action'] as String == 'Overview'  ? 'activeStatMenuItem' : statMenuItem')" })
```

it adds the `statMenuItem`-class to all the items.

Making the strings in the middle there expressed with `'mystring'` makes it stop complaining, but does not solve my problem - it just adds the active CSS-class to all the items.

[image: Using ' in the string]

I've found that if I just make everything one long string, and no `"` nor `'` in the middle, makes everything stop complaining, but it also seems that it evaluates every expression to true, so all the items then get the active CSS-class.

I am very inexperienced with both Visual Studio, ASP.NET and Razor (started on this project on thursday), so I may (/probably) have missed something simple. Thanks in advance for your patience.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing is to create a variable, do your presentation logic and then just assign this string value to the @class of your link.

```
@{
   var myClass = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"] as String == "Overview"  ? "activeStatMenuItem" : "statMenuItem";
}
```

and then later

```
@Html.ActionLink("Oversikt", "Overview", "Statistics", null, new {@class= myClass })
```

should do the trick... hope you get the idea, haven't tested it, so it may be slightly different.

It's never a good idea to combine too many steps into one line. It's really hard to find the problem that way and it's harder to read and figure out, what's really going on.

Comment: It did the trick, thank you very much! I still wonder why that works, but writing it in directly does not.

Comment: You have problems with your quotes ("), so it can't be parsed correctly. There are ways to escape it \", but it gets really ugly soon.